# Access Token is null after retrieving Friends List using Facebook C# SDK 5.4.1.0

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm new to Facebook C# SDK and i'm maintaining an existing FB Apps using Facebook C# SDK 5.4.1.0. This Apps is working fine until the recent FB updates. I aware that i should update my SDK but i need to find a temporary solution before i can invest time to upgrade the SDK to v6.

I'm facing a issue where Access Token in FacebookWebContext.Current are becoming NULL after the apps performing an Friend list query using fbquery. This work fine for usual view as the Authorization process will redirect user to a page to refresh the token.

In my case i'm performing an AJAX post to MVC Function with HttpPost and CustomAuthorize Attribute. When the Access Token is null, the OnAuthorization will return me a HTML string with URL. I've try to redirect user to that URL but the URL doesn't eventually perform the post as the data for processing it has been lost.

So my question is, is there any other way to reset the access token without performing an redirection?  Is there any other temporary solution to make the application work while i can buy some time to upgrade the SDK?